# jsf ajax viewcope reloads whole page

Tags: ajax, jsf, prerender

when i perform an ajax call with:

```
<h:form id="showEntriesForm">
    <h:commandButton value="Einträge anzeigen" onclick="javascript:this.disabled=true;" id="showEntryb">
    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render=":main :showEntriesButton" listener="#{bean.showEntries}"/>
    </h:commandButton> 
</h:form>
```

it executes all the @prerender commands again and it seems like it reloads the whole page.
i thought that ajax would just reload the parts I tell it to reload?

or is prerender always executed? do I need something else than prerender to fetch the GET-variables only once when the view is created?

regards

Answer (score 1):

`@Prerender` event gets fired before the given view gets rendered, which means the annotated methods should get called even if only some of the components belonging to the view need to be updated.

Not sure what your methods do, but maybe you should try the `@Init` annotation.

Comment: Hi, my methods are doing sql-requests to load init data into the bean. so @Init will fix this? my prerender looks like this:

<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.executeQuery}" />

Comment: I dont' have a @Init annotation?

Comment: You don't? Please post the import for your `@Prerender` annotation